# os.system('wc -l < <filename>') with Python

Tags: python, linux

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

FileLineCount       = int (os.system('wc -l < DQ1J1'))
LineCount           = str (FileLineCount -5)

print 'FileLineCount: =' , FileLineCount
print 'LineCount: =' , LineCount
```

I'm getting an output

```
505
FileLineCount: = 0
LineCount: = -5
```

But I'm expecting an output

```
505
FileLineCount: = 505
LineCount: = 500
```

Can someone help me out here, Where am I going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `os.system` doesn't return the value that a command prints to the screen, it returns its exit code. Try `subprocess.check_output` instead.

Comment: @Kevin, you should probably put that as an answer, such that the question can be closed.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post it as an answer, because I'm on Windows and can't verify that `check_output` would actually work in this situation. In particular, I don't know if the "<" separator is supported, or whether you need to set `shell=True`, or what. Anyone is free to expand upon my suggestion in their own answer, of course :-)

Comment: @Kevin it works, I tired it.